# Magento2- How to validate coupon code to cart before apply

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.2.2, coupon, coupon-codes

How to validate `Coupon Code` to `Cart` before apply in **Magento 2**?

Is it possible?

Comment: Apply coupon code box is already there in cart page and by default magento validate the coupon code.

Comment: Yes, I want to catch that event and add the additional functionality after the coupon validation check

Answer (score 1):

A coupon code is applied or removed through the `Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\CouponPost` controller. Depending on what you want to do you can either use a plugin or an observer.

**Why shouldn't I use an observer?**
What do I mean by "depending on"? What I mean by that is that an observer shouldn't be used to change the outcome. It should be used to react to some kind of event happening, but not change it.

Or at least, not outside of the data passed to the observer. Some events pass a data object which you can manipulate. An example would be the `payment_method_is_active` event which gets passed a `result` which is a data object. Using this data object the observer can specify whether the payment method is / should be active or not.

**Plugin**
Using a plugin you can add a `beforeExecute` and bind this plugin to the `Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\CouponPost` controller.

```php
class PostCouponCodeValidation {
    public function beforeExecute(CouponPost $subject) {
        $couponCode = $subject->getRequest()->getParam('coupon_code');

        // means that this request should remove the current coupon code from the quote
        $remove = $subject->getRequest()->getParam('remove');

        // do your stuff
    }
}
```

**Observer**
Magento dispatches a couple of generic events whenever a controller is dispatched.

- `controller_action_predispatch`
- `controller_action_predispatch_{route}`
- `controller_action_predispatch_{action}`

---

- `controller_action_postdispatch`
- `controller_action_postdispatch_{route}`
- `controller_action_postdispatch_{action}`

We can use these events to observe any dispatched controller. In this case that would be our `Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\CouponPost` controller.

If you want to use an observer for this you can use the `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_couponpost` event to observer whenever the `Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\CouponPost` is dispatched.

**Keep in mind...**
Please keep in mind that within the `Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\CouponPost` controller there is some manipulation and validation of the coupon code. Such as trimming it and validate that it isn't empty.

Using a plugin or the `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_couponpost` event makes it so that this manipulation and validation of the coupon code hasn't happened yet. So you should perform this (if necessary and applicable to what you're trying to do) yourself within the plugin or observer.